# How do I display information in table with a filter in R?

Tags: r

I currently have the following code:

```
KickerExpectation <- nfl.kick %>%
group_by(Kicker) %>%
summarize(total = sum(expectedmakes),numkicks=n(),makesperkick=total/numkicks)
KickerExpectation

and the following output:
```

```
Kicker    Total    numkicks    makesperkick
<fct>      <dbl>   <int>       <dbl>
1 Akers    283      336        0.842
2 Andrus   4.19     5          0.838
3 Bailey   132      162        0.812
```

How do I make it so that i only see Kickers with numkicks > 10?

Do I have to use mutate(atLeast = numkicks>10) at some point? If so, how?

thank you in advance!!!

Comment: The examples in https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter.html (as well as `?dplyr::filter`) might be useful to look at. An advantage to sample code in the `?`/help docs is that they are almost always 100% reproducible (built-in or self-built data samples) and, if written well (tidyverse docs generally *are*), walk through 2 or more different perspectives for using the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After this, we can do a `filter` to keep only rows where the 'numkicks' is greater than 10

```
library(dplyr)
out <- KickerExpectation  %>%
              filter(numkicks > 10)
```